# Can I write business logic in @RequestScoped beans instead of a Stateless EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, ejb-3.0, interceptor

I want to know if I can use classes annotated with `@RequestScoped` instead of `@Stateless` to write my business logic.

I have some `EJBs` which have some business logic and no database code. The only reason I declared it as an `EJB` is to take advantage of `interceptors`. Since there is no need for transaction management, I think declaring it as `@RequestScoped` will make more sense.

Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: I suppose you are designing a REST service. Don't know what business logic you are planning to have in your interceptor, but you can probably achieve the same result with standard JEE filters bound to a rest service. Another alternative to manipulate request/response, if my guess about REST is right, is to use a MessageBodyReader and a MessageBodyWriter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Named` and `@RequestScoped` if u want to program your business logic depend on the single HTTP request (An object which is defined as `@RequestScoped` is created once for every request and is shared by all the bean that inject it throughout a request). But in the case of `UserTransaction`,`Datasource`,thread safety and inceptor will be an issue then stick with `@stateless`.